# Passing a Smarty variable to a php file using HTML form.

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, smarty

I have this form inside a Smarty template file :

```
<form method="post" action="manswer.php">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" >
            <tr>
                <td style = "vertical-align:top;">Answer:</td>
                <td><textarea rows="8" cols="50" name='answer_text' ></textarea></td>
            <tr>
                <td><br/></td>
                <td><input  id = 'answerbutton' type='submit'  value='Cevapla!' /></td>
            </tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

I also have **{$q_id}** variable inside that template file. How can I pass this variable to manswer.php with that HTML form? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" value="{$q_id}" name="something" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a hidden input field.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $q_id;?>" name="something" />
```

Then to retrieve it using CodeIgniter

```
...
$something = $this->input->post('something');
...
```